# MYSQL join query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, join, syntax

I am trying to join three tables.  The first is a table of groups, the second of joiners and the third of users.   Logic is I start out with id of group, then join group on joiners by groupid.  Finally since I want names as well as ids I pull them from users table by joining users on userid.  But alas not working. MYSQL is throwing an error saying "error near 'groups' g which usually means right before that.  What am I missing?

groups
id | name |userid

joiners
id | groupid | userid

users 
id | firstname

```
$sql = "SELECT g.*,j.userid,u.firstname,u.id
FROM 'groups' g
LEFT JOIN 'joiners' j
ON g.id = j.groupid
LEFT JOIN 'users' u
ON j.userid = u.id
WHERE g.id = 22";
```

Comment: You say that it is reporting "error near 'group' g", however, in your SQL, it appears to be "'groups' g" -- did you recently change the name of the table "group" to "groups"? Since "group" is a reserved word, it would be a bad choice for a table name.

Comment: that was a typo.  Since this is on test server, I tried changing field name and no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambiguous terms such as tables and columns should be escaped using back ticks:

```
$sql = "SELECT g.*,j.userid,u.firstname,u.id
FROM `groups` g
LEFT JOIN `joiners` j ON g.id = j.groupid
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON j.userid = u.id
WHERE g.id = 22
```

This is assuming the rest of your query is correct, because I don't see the end of your string  ;-)

Comment: the table names are all escaped with back ticks.  Are you recommending I escape all the columns as in 'j.userid', 'u.userid'?  I don't see what you have changed in your version.  There is a " and semicolon at end of sql otherwise it would have thrown a different error.  Still at a loss....

Comment: no, just the the ' is not appropriate for table escaping, use backtick instead (same for columns)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, what I thought were ticks were apostrophes, not backticks.  I thought they were backticks.  Sorry, did not understand your answer. As former asp person, how I hate PHP punctuation. grrr.